# Can any meromorphic function be represented as a product of zeroes and poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given any meromorphic function, can it be represented as

$$c\prod_i (z-z_i)^{n_i} $$

where $ n_i\in\mathbb Z$ and $n_i> 0$ denotes the multiplicity of the zero $ z_i $ and $ n_i <0$ for the poles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Not all, but...

Turns out this is more complicated than [user170431's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/906760/163) suggested, though it hinted at the correct direction.

Given a meromorphic function $f(z)$ with poles at $\{p_i\}$ of multiplicites $\{n_{p_i}\}$, one can indeed use [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) to obtain a holomorphic function

$$h(z) = f(z) - \sum_i \pi_{p_i}(1/(z-p_i))$$

where $\pi_{p_i}$ denotes a polynomial of degree $n_{p_i}$, and due to their finite order (meromorphic functions don't have essential singularities) one can expand $f(z)$ to the common denominator.

What the other answer and my question's assumption did however neglect was the full extend of the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), according to which $h(z)$ actually factorizes into

$$h(z) = e^{g(z)}\prod_j(z-z_j)^{n_{z_j}}$$

where $n_{z_j}$ denotes the multiplicity of the zero $z_j$ and $g(z)$ is an entire function. Note that I simplified matters here, for infinitely many zeros (or of infinite multiplicity) parts of the exponential are inside the product as "elementary factors" in order to have the infinite product converge. In my sloppy notation, they are part of $\exp g(z)$ though.

Therefore, the actual representation of a meromorphic function is

$$f(z) = e^{g(z)}\prod_i(z-z_i)^{n_i}$$

(now the $z_i$ also include the poles again, as in the question's notation). Only if there are finitely many zeros of finite multiplicities (i.e. a quotient of two polynomials), the representation without an exponential in front (i.e. a constant $g(z)$) is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) combined with the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) after reducing to the common denominator.

Comment: Thanks! The way it's started there, one needs to expand by the product of the sum denominators and use Weierstrass factorization to be more precise

Comment: Sure;you're right about the use of Weistrass; I guess I was being a bit lazy.

Comment: no worries, it's straightforward from there then :)

Comment: Turns out I was slightly too eager accepting your answer - as [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/138549/163) mentions, the exponential function cannot be represented this way